# accessing a static variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables, static

I'm using Qt Creator to try and create a basic calculator app. I was trying to test out the first few methods and had to write one in order to make the rest of the coding easier, however, that method isn't compiling. I'm trying to access a static variable that holds the current value of the Calculator screen, but it keeps giving me:

```
C:\Users\****\Documents\Qt Projects\SimpleCalculator\calculator.cpp:15: error: C2248: 'Calculator::currVal' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Calculator'
```

Here is the Calculator.cpp

```
    #include "calculator.h"
#include <QLCDNumber>

Calculator::Calculator(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Calculator)
{
    ans = 0;
    currVal = 0;
    setupUi(this);

}

//problem method
QString getNewVal(qint64 nextDig)
{
    //--------------------------------------------
    long long int val = Calculator::currVal;//this is where I am trying to access the variable
    //--------------------------------------------
    if(nextDig==0)
    {
        if(val > 0)
        {
            QString str = QString::number(val);
            str.append("0");
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
    else if(nextDig==1)
    {
        QString str = QString::number(val);
        str.append("1");
        return str;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Calculator::on_Zero_clicked()
{
    ui->Display->display(getNewVal(0));
    currVal = ui->Display->intValue();
}

void Calculator::on_One_clicked()
{

}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H
#include "ui_calculator.h"

class Calculator : public QWidget, private Ui::Calculator
{

    Q_OBJECT


public:
     Calculator(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void on_Zero_clicked();
    void on_One_clicked();
private:
    Ui::Calculator *ui;
    QString getNewVal(quint64);
    static long long int ans;
    static long long int currVal;


};

long long int Calculator::ans = 0;
long long int Calculator::currVal = 0;
#endif


 // CALCULATOR_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that `getNewVal` belongs to `Calculator`

```
QString Calculator::getNewVal(quint64 nextDig)
//      ^^^^^^^^^^             ^
//   This was missing          |
//                             |
//   Add 'u' above to match the declaration
```

Otherwise, C++ thinks that this is a free-standing function (despite the fact that you have declared a member function with the same name inside `Calculator`).

You also need to move the two definitions

```
long long int Calculator::ans = 0;
long long int Calculator::currVal = 0;
```

from the header file to the implementation file.

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: "C:\Users\****\Documents\Qt Projects\SimpleCalculator\calculator.cpp:15: error: C2511: 'QString Calculator::getNewVal(qint64)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Calculator'"

Comment: @user2337530 That's because you are missing `u` in the implementation: you types `qint64` instead of `quint64`.

Comment: Gotta love programming. -_- I totally missed that. Now, it'll compile. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Calculator::currVal;//this is where I am trying to access the variable
```

Won't work because the value is declared private (as indicated by the warning) in your header:

```
private:
    Ui::Calculator *ui;
    QString getNewVal(quint64);
    static long long int ans;
    **static long long int currVal;**
```

and your function:

```
QString getNewVal(qint64 nextDig)
```

is not part of the class.

Comment: Well, when I change the method to: "QString Calculator::getNewVal(***)"

I get this error: "C:\Users\****\Documents\Qt Projects\SimpleCalculator\calculator.cpp:18: error: C2511: 'QString Calculator::getNewVal(qint64)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Calculator'"

Answer (score 1):

This

```
static long long int currVal;
```

is private!

try:

```
public:
   static long long int currVal;
```

or create a getter method for that.

also you can make the `getNewVal` a friend function of your class:

```
public:
    friend QString ::getNewVal(qint64 nextDig);
```

Comment: I've tried that, but doing that gives me several errors. I know it's private, but when I put it under public, I get about 6 errors.

Comment: Did you tried a getter method?, like static int getCurrVal(){return currVal;};

Comment: ah cool, didn't know you could make a global function a friend :)